# Display multi level list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two model classes

```
public class Genre
{
    [Key]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string GenreName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Movie
{

    [Key]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }

    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public string MovieDirector { get; set; }
    public int MovieYear { get; set; }
    public string MovieDesc { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }


    public int GenreRefId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GenreRefId")]

    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
}
```

I know how to display a list of these objects on their own but my project requires that I list:

- Each genre + the top 5 newest movies added to the list

I'm not even sure where to begin. Since you cannot use two models in a view... how do i gather and display both lists?

any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `Genre` contains `Movie` so all you need is for the view to be `@IEnumerable<Genre>` and use nested loops

Comment: Hey Stephen, Thank you for taking the time.

    '@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GenreName)</h3>

                @foreach (var GenreName in Model)
                {
                    <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => GenreName.Movies)</h3>
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }'

Is this sort of what you mean? What am I missing?

Comment: `@foreach (var genre in Model) { @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => genre.GenreName) @foreach (var movie in genre.Movies) { .....`

Comment: the list comes out like this - >

Fantasy
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Genre_BD15194A8DE845FA04211AF31B268E603FD17F36A7B03470F7F441B6A4DD0A4BSystem.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Genre_BD15194A8DE845FA04211AF31B268E603FD17F36A7B03470F7F441B6A4DD0A4B
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Genre_BD15194A8DE845FA04211AF31B268E603FD17F36A7B03470F7F441B6A4DD0A4BSystem.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Genre_BD15194A8DE845FA04211AF31B268E603FD17F36A7B03470F7F441B6A4DD0A4B

Comment: Edit your question to show the GET method (how you get the collection) and the code in the view  you have tried.

Comment: you were totally correct and I had typed it out wrong. you are a king! thank you so much!

Comment: Is your question also about fetching the right data (get genre with movies, order movies by creationdate, take top 5? Or is it only about displaying the data (then you should include some Frontend code)?

Comment: Hey grek, you had it correct on the first one